# setting up mysql-python on Snow Leopard

Tags: mysql-python

I have successfully installed py27-mysql from MacPorts and MySQL-python-1.2.3c1 on a machine running Snow Leopard. Because I have MySQL 5.1.48 in an odd location (/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql/), I had to edit the setup.cfg file when I installed mysql-python. However, now that it's installed, I'm still getting the error "ImportError: No module named MySQLdb" when I run "import MySQLdb" in python. What is left to install? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts' py27-mysql, MySQL-python, and MySQLdb are all synonyms for the same thing. If you successfully installed py27-mysql, you should not need anything else, and it's possible you've messed up your python site-packages. Also, make sure you are invoking the right python binary, i.e. MacPorts' python27 and not the one that comes with Mac OS X.